# ReactiveCocoa recurring signal

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have the following code:

```
- (RACSignal *)addSyncTask:(RACSignal *)task withInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval
{
    return [[task concat:[[RACSignal empty] delay:interval]] then:^RACSignal *{
        return [self addSyncTask:task withInterval:interval];
    }];
}

- (void)setupFooSync
{
    RACSignal *signal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [self.API syncFooWithCompletion:^(id response, NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];
        return nil;
    }];
    [self addSyncTask:signal withInterval:60];
}
```

The idea is that once `setupFooSync` is invoked, the sync will occur once every 60 seconds until the containing instance is deallocated. However, with the code above, the sync never occurs. When I change `+createSignal:` to `+startLazilyWithScheduler:`, it occurs only once. I am guessing that since the same sync signal is being reused every time, there needs to be some sort of reset. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that concat doesn't trigger the needed subscribe method, try this instead:

```
[[[task then:^RACSignal *{
    return [[RACSignal interval:5 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] take:1];
}] repeat] subscribeCompleted:^{

}];
```